# Are workarounds available for the MongoDB 16MB file size limitation?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm using
aggregate query which results more than 16MB so query is failing in
MongoDB.

I KNOW THIS IS EXISTING/ALREADY KNOWN ISSUE.

However, I don't understand what workarounds are alternatives may be available. How can I avoid the impact of this issue?

Comment: These should be stored in GridFS if they are bigger than 16MB. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/ or you can store them in the actual file system and store the path. Other than that I don't think there is much else you can do.

Comment: Is this really an aggregation-framework issue, or the BSON document-size limit?

Comment: Try to save the file on Amazon S3 and save the url of the file in MongoDB instead of entire file.

Comment: its BSON doc limitation, but workaround should be in the aggregation may be be, i dnt know

Comment: @GauravGupta I'm hitting mondoDB and using the aggregation logic, there its failing

Comment: aggregate results can be more than 16MB in total, but each doc in the results much be less than 16MB. Is it that per-doc limit that you're hitting?

Comment: Quick googling pointed me to GridFs as @MikeCheel has mentioned.

Comment: @JohnnyHK, no, overall result is more than 16MB, there only we are getting MONGO DB error saying exceeding 16MB

Comment: There is no 16MB limit on the overall result. See [docs about the limits](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline-limits/).

Comment: @JohnnyHK, it says in the link you pinged,check this line total size of the result set  saying,Earlier versions of the aggregate command can only return a single BSON document that contains the result set and will produce an error if the if the total size of the result set exceeds the BSON Document Size limit.

Comment: Are you stuck on a pre-2.6 version of MongoDB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to MongoDB documentation

> The maximum BSON document size is 16 megabytes. The maximum document
>   size helps ensure that a single document cannot use excessive amount
>   of RAM or, during transmission, excessive amount of bandwidth.

In newer versions MongoDB aggregate operation returns cursor to overcome limitation of max document size and result of any size  as in previous versions results were returned in single document.

Comment: We are using Mongos 3.0.7 version. Actually this is failing at DB query level. Query results this error in MongoDB

Comment: @user1742919 Specifying cursor option as argument in db.collection.aggregate() method will return cursor